# Output date is not proper when the script is run using cron

Tags: scripting, cron, date

The below line should provide an output date which when run manually gives an proper output such as `Fri Jul 17 01:42:07 2015`.
But when run using cron, it gives the epoch date i.e. `Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969`

```
job_date=`iwgetwfobj $i | sed -n 2p |tr -s '=' '@'|awk -F'@' '{print $6}'|tr - d \" |tr -d \>| perl -e 'print localtime(<>) . "\n";'`
```

Please let me know the change to be made. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: insert a `| tee /tmp/lets-see.log` just before the `| sed` and see what's wrong with the second line of the output of `iwgetwfobj` in `/tmp/lets-see.log`.

Comment: `TZ=US/Eastern perl -E 'say scalar localtime(0)'` indicates you're getting epoch 0 somehow. In addition to the `iwgetwfobj` bit, what is `$i` and where did it come from?

Comment: Here $i is holding a job ID. iwgetfwjob uses the same to get information on the jobs. Further the output is processed to fetch the date of activation of the job from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by putting the path before the CLT iwgetwfobj. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The cron daemon can't find `iwgetwfobj`, as it's not on the minimal path (`/usr/bin:/bin`)

> Several  environment  variables  are  set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon.  *[...]* `PATH` is set to `"/usr/bin:/bin"`.   *[...]*  `PATH` may be overridden by settings in the crontab.

Either set `PATH` explicitly at the start of the crontab, or write the full pathname of `iwgetwfobj` and any other commands not in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.